# Modular Sinatra - routes not working - structuring config.ru and multiple controllers to handle routes

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am following the recipe found on this tutorial on Sinatra::Base
https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/sinatra-up-and/9781449306847/ch04.html

I am having an issue getting my routes to work, currently only one route works and that is `get '/'` which loads from `ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base`  home.erb.

the route in my second controller which is named `ExampleController < ApplicationController` does not work

**config.ru** (relevant code only)

```
# Load Controllers and models
Dir.glob('./{controllers,models}/*.rb').each { |file| require file }

map('/example') { run ExampleController }
map('/') { run ApplicationController }
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base
  # set folder for root
  set :root, File.expand_path("../app", Dir.pwd)

  # don't enable logging when running tests
  configure :production, :development do
    enable :logging
  end

  get '/' do
    title "Home.erb"
    erb :home
  end

  not_found do
    title 'Not Found!'
    erb :not_found
  end

end
```

**example_controller.rb** which the routes will not load from currently

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController

  get '/example' do
    title "Example Page"
    erb :example
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, based off the tutorial, that you've used the route `/example` in both your config.ru file and in the routes for the ExampleController. This might mean your local url might end up as 'http://localhost:4567/example/example' . By the looks of things your example_controller.rb file should look like this, with '/' as the route:

**example_controller.rb**

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController

  get '/' do
    title "Example Page"
    erb :example
  end

end
```

It also looks like you need to `require 'sinatra/base'` in your config.ru file.

**config.ru**

```
# Load Controllers and models
require 'sinatra/base'
Dir.glob('./{helpers,controllers}/*.rb').each { |file| require file }

map('/example') { run ExampleController }
map('/') { run ApplicationController }
```

Also your application_controller.rb appears to be missing your helpers and set views isn't included.

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base
  helpers ApplicationHelper

  # set folder for templates to ../views, but make the path absolute
  set :views, File.expand_path('../../views', __FILE__)

  # don't enable logging when running tests
  configure :production, :development do
    enable :logging
  end

  get '/' do
    title "Home.erb"
    erb :home
  end

  # will be used to display 404 error pages
  not_found do
    title 'Not Found!'
    erb :not_found
  end
end
```

Comment: unfortunately it still throws an error, WEBrick is saying `"GET /example HTTP/1.1" 404 553 0.0030`

Comment: did you restart the server?

Comment: I've noticed another bit of info you are missing relative to the tutorial. I've updated my answer above. Did you need to include your helpers in `{controllers,models}`? (i.e. `{helpers,controllers,models}`)

Comment: Hi, I've managed to simulate this tutorial and get it working. There's a few typos in the tutorial and by the looks of things you are missing a fair bit of info. Have updated my answer above but, if it still doesn't work, I can push what I did to my GitHub repo and you're welcome to pull it and compare scripts to see where you went wrong. :-)